# MURA - Getting started

Tags: mysql, tomcat, coldfusion, mura, lucee

I have just installed Mura CMS.
I have Lucee installed and setup.  However, it seems I am not completely "there" yet.

I can get to the Mura Page, but something seems missing:

When I go to: `http://localhost:8888/cms` I get a: `404 requested page could not be found` and then right below this, we see:

> Sample Modal Window This is just a sample…
>
> Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Praesent
>   suscipit iaculis libero sed tristique. Quisque mollis dolor non tellus
>   placerat vitae sodales lectus porta. Curabitur ut suscipit tellus.
>   Maecenas rhoncus, ante etc.

Environment is:

- LINUX Mint (Rebecca 17.1) - It is my personal laptop
- MySQL 5.5 (from Software Manager)
- MySQL WorkBench (Created Mura DB and User)
- Lucee Express 4.5.1.000 (and also includes Tomcat 8) - Created the DSN in server

I am wanting to work with Mura as I am on a migration project to Mura from another CMS.

I did follow the information it seems to be the most relevant to start with Lucee: [Installing Tomcat and Lucee on OS X using the lucee.war file](https://bitbucket.org/lucee/lucee/wiki/Installing%20Tomcat%20and%20Lucee%20on%20OS%20X%20using%20the%20lucee%20.war%20file)

It seems I am missing something pretty simple at this point as is shown by this screen cap.[image: Mura Admin Panel]

It does not look anything like the admin panel from their site:
[image: Mura Admin Panel - from Mura]

Comment: It looks like the css file(s) is not being loaded. Check the browsers tools too see if it has a 404 error

Comment: I am a bit confused.  I do see one css file for flow player under Mura, but there is nothing else either in Mura or in Lucee.

Answer (score 1):

I wound up getting some additional help.  These steps were what was used under Linux Mint.

- Setup MySQL and MySQL Workbench or phpMyAdmin would work as well
- Created a new database and database user as directed in the Installation.txt from Mura
- Insure that you have Lucee configured (creating the DSN) and that you are able to login
- Moved Lucee Express to /home/your_home/lucee and made sure that Lucee works
- Deleted all of the content from /home/your_home/lucee/webapps/ROOT
- Extracted out the contents of the Mura.zip into /home/your_home/lucee/webapps/ROOT
- Changed /home/your_home/lucee/webapps/ROOT/config/settings.ini.cfm at line 27 to be context= (blank)
- Ran startup.sh at /home/your_home/lucee/bin
  Navigated to http://localhost:8888 and the site comes up fine and was able to login.

Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

**Addressing the CSS issue**

When a non standard ports, the base tag needs to be set

```
<base href="http://localhost:8888/mura-6.2.6271/">
```

OR perhaps

```
<base href="http://localhost:8888/mura-6.2.6271/admin">
```

This is set in a layouts file

Answer (score 0):

Try editing your `/config/settings.ini.cfm` file by setting the context attribute to the value or the nested path to the Mura root.  So if the Mura is access via `/cms/admin` the context value would be `/cms`

```
context=/cms
```

The reload the application by putting `?appreload` in at request to the Mura root.  The `appreloadke`y is also configurable in the `settings.ini.cfm`.

Comment: In Chrome can you open up the debugger and on the network panel see where the links for CSS and JS are pointing?